# Why is this spring bean not initialised? It is always null.

Tags: java, web-services, spring, soap, spring-mvc

I have a message factory bean configured as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:ws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="soapMessageFactory" class="javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory" factory-method="newInstance" />
    <bean id="saajMessageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
            <constructor-arg ref="soapMessageFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myService" class="com.mypackage.TestEndPoint">
        <property name="saajMessageFactory" ref="saajMessageFactory" />
    </bean> 



</beans>
```

The TestEndpoint class looks like this

```
@Endpoint
public class TestEndPoint {


    ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
    SaajSoapMessageFactory saajMessageFactory;


    @PayloadRoot(namespace="http://ws.mypackage.com", localPart="downloadSaajMessageRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public JAXBElement<DownloadResponseSaajType> invoke(@RequestPayload DownloadSaajMessageRequest req, MessageContext context ) throws Exception  {

        DownloadResponseSaajType response = new DownloadResponseSaajType();
        //DownloadResponseSaajType.PayLoad payload = new DownloadResponseSaajType.PayLoad();    

        DataHandler handler = new javax.activation.DataHandler(new FileDataSource("c:\\temp\\maven-feather.png"));

            SaajSoapMessage message = saajMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage();
            message.addAttachment("picture", handler);
            message.addAttachment("picture", handler);

           //payload.setMessagePayLoad(handler);
            //response.setPayLoad(payload);

            response.setRequestName("NAMEOF");
            context.setResponse(message);
            return objectFactory.createDownloadSaajMessageResponse(response); 

    }

    public void setSaajMessageFactory(SaajSoapMessageFactory saajMessageFactory){
        this.saajMessageFactory = saajMessageFactory;
        }

        public SaajSoapMessageFactory getSaajMessageFactory(){
            return saajMessageFactory;
        }
}
```

I am having a few problems trying to get the endpoint to work and when i tried to debug the code i found that saajMessageFactory is never initialised and it is always null. Have i done something wrong with the configuration?

Comment: I am not. "myService" is just the id i have given to the com.mypackage.TestEndPoint class so that i can initialise the property in TestEndPoint class. Is that wrong how i have done it?

Comment: get the myService bean from the ApplicationContext and see if  saajMessageFactory is initialised properly.

Comment: How? Do i need to add it in the configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping bean to your configuration xml.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping"/>
```